# How do I get rid of the "THE END" screen in Super Mario World?

Tags: wii-u, virtual-console, super-mario-world

I finished Super Mario World on the Wii U Virtual Console and I watched the credits. At the end was Mario, Peach and Luigi standing there with the words THE END. It won't go away no matter what I do. Whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make the screen go away with your controller. You will have to quit the game through the Wii menu or reset your system.

Comment: This is correct, I would add as well that the early Mario games (SMB2, SMB3, SMW) would have the player reset or power down the console when you reached the end.  While I can't speculate if it was a design or engineering choice, it was a normal thing to do for some games in that NES/Early-SNES period.